# How to assert a condition pass or fail in pytest for web UI testing

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

```
def test_review():
review_score = driver.find_element(By.ID, "acrCustomerReviewText")
assert "review_score" >= "4"
price = driver.find_element(By.ID, "corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div")
assert "price" <= "4000"
```

I want to review the rating if it's less than 4 fail the test otherwise  pass it
The second one is similar
I checked the product price if the price is more than 4000 and failed it
How do I know if it's passing or failing?

Comment: This answer seems too broad and shows lack of investigation from your side. For starters, pytest functions should start with test_function_name(self, ...). Please read the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class) or an updated tutorial on pytest.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ferreiradev I have edited the questions. please check

Comment: Question answered. Please accept it under the upvote arrow if it suits your needs. That said, I still highly recommend that you take a complete tutorial on testing because there is more to testing that having the right code; how to come up with tests that properly test the application needs is also a big deal.

Comment: I highly appreciate your response @ferreiradev. I will take a tutorial on testing to learn how to properly test an application. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following creates a fake html that fits your requirement and then uses two separate test with pytest.

Note that `fixture_get_driver` is called automatically by the test and serves to provide a global webdriver object. `setup_module()` is also automatically called by pytest.

Another valid, and arguably better approach, is to use classes with pytest.

To run the two tests, do:

```
>>> pytest test.py --verbose
collected 2 items

test.py::test_simple_customer_review PASSED [ 50%]
test.py::test_price PASSED [ 100%]
===== 2 passed in 7.31s =====
```

---

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pytest


def mockup_html():
    with open("mockup.html", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as mockup:
        mockup.write(
            '<p id="acrCustomerReviewText">4</p>'
            '<p id="corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div">3500</p>'
        )


@pytest.fixture(scope="module", name="get_driver")
def fixture_get_driver() -> webdriver.Firefox:
    """A fixture that uses yield to provide teardown for the webdriver"""
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    # driver.get("https://google.com")
    driver.get("file:///" + os.path.abspath("./mockup.html"))
    yield driver
    print("teardown driver")
    driver.quit()


def setup_module():
    """setup any state specific to the execution of the given module."""
    mockup_html()


def test_simple_customer_review(get_driver, expected_min_score=4):
    try:
        elem = get_driver.find_element(By.ID, "acrCustomerReviewText")
        # Check is expected text exists
        assert int(elem.text) >= expected_min_score
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # State that the test fails because elem does not exist
        assert False
    except ValueError:
        # Element content is not numeric; fail the test
        assert False

def test_price(get_driver, expected_price_limit="3500"):
    try:
        elem = get_driver.find_element(By.ID, "corePriceDisplay_desktop_feature_div")
        # Check is actual price matches expected price limit
        assert float(elem.text) <= float(expected_price_limit)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # State that the test fails because elem does not exist
        assert False
    except ValueError:
        # Element content is not numeric; fail the test
        assert False
```